# How to change props ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, api, redux, react-redux

I have a question about changing props in ReactJs component.
I'm getting data from API (Django backend) and using redux (acions etc) I can get them as props.
However Im not sure how to change them in the way that I will be able to pass them back to backend. 
Any ideas how to do it?
Best regards!

Comment: "I can get them as props" what do you mean? Why is it the only way you get data from the API?

Comment: *pass them back to backend* - requests are considered side effects. They belong to Redux middleware or side-effect React libs - Thunk, Saga, etc. Consider providing https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your case if you have specific problems with implementing that.

Answer (score 0):

You just need another action/api POST/PATCH to update the relevant dataand do another GET (action called to fetch the data initially) to reload the new data/props in the reducer